# 'Надо было бы' - present or past conditional?

Tags: tense, conditional

- Что ***бы*** ты ***выбрал***, если тебе ***надо было бы*** писать видео про это каждый день?

If I understand correctly, 'Что бы ты выбрал' can mean both 'what would you choose' in present conditional and 'what would you have chosen' in past conditional, depending on contexts.

But can the same thing be said about "надо было бы"? Can it be both 'if you had to write' in present conditional and 'if you'd had to write' in past conditional, depending on contexts?

Comment: Yes, it's ambiguous.

Comment: The _position_ of the second **бы** needs correction: _Что бы ты выбрал, если **бы** тебе надо было писать видео про это каждый день?_

Answer (score 3):

The conditional mood in Russian is 'timeless'. Specific time references may be needed to resolve the ambiguity:

- Если *бы* у меня *был* миллион долларов... If I had a million dollars...
- Если *бы* у меня **год назад** *был* миллион долларов... If I had had a million dollars a year ago...

However, motion verbs do carry some temporal meaning:

- Если бы мне не надо было **ходить** на работу... If I didn't have (hadn't had) to go to work **every day**...
- Если бы мне не надо было **идти** на работу... If I didn't have to go to work **now**...

Answer (score 0):

There's no tense in the Russian Conditional mood. The time can be figured out from the context. 
**Что бы вы делали, если бы вам надо было принимать важные решения каждый день? Моя работа этого требует.** - Present. 
**Что бы вы делали, если бы вам надо было принимать важные решения за других? А ведь я был моложе их всех.** - Past. 
Though the category of Perfect (совершенный и несовершенный вид) is observed with the Conditional mood. 
**Если бы я ходил на работу** - that means if I went (had gone) to my work (regularly) 
**Если бы я пришел на работу** - that is if I came (had come) to work (today, by that time) 
**Если бы я шел на работу** и видел, что здание сносят, я бы вернулся домой. - If I were going to my work... (that is a process, hence it is Continuous).

Comment: please, provide answers that add some new information compared to answers already provided